# UnInstalling ClickOnce using MSI wrapper - Error

Tags: wpf, clickonce, windows-installer

I have clickonce application and one of the requirement is to uninstall the application even when the application is running. So I created a MSI wrapper which installs the clickonce app, updates the registry etc. and is also used to Uninstall the clickonce app.

Project Structure

- ClickOnce application - deployed to a server http://someserver/app.client.application.
- Console application 1

  - This launches a process calling the above url while the MSI is installing
  - while the MSI is uninstalling, if the clickonce app is running the app is closed/killed, the clickonce uninstallstring is read and a process launches trying to uninstall the clickonce app
- Console application 2 which creates a eventlog source while installing and removes the same while uninstalling
- MSI Wrapper - Which is used to install and uninstall the clickonce application.

This has custom actions set

```
- Install
    * Primary output from console Application 2
    * Primary output from console Application 1

- Uninstall
    * Primary output from console Application 1
    * Primary output from console Application 2
```

The console application 1 & 2 hook into BeforeInstall and AfterInstall events on the Installer.

Everything works fine while i install, the event log source gets created, the clickonce application launches and installs. The install part runs smooth and i have no issues.

But i have problems while uninstalling, the MSI uninstalls itself and call the process to uninstall clickonce which throws prompt and removes the eventlog source.

### Here are the error details

There is a pop up which says 'Uninstall of the application did not succeed. see detail for more information'.

Clicking on details button opens up the error details text

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
Windows             : 6.1.7600.0 (Win32NT)
Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.239
System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.239 (RTMGDR.030319-2300)
dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
dfshim.dll          : 4.0.31106.0 (Main.031106-0000)

IDENTITIES
Deployment Identity     : XXXXX.Client.application, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0000000000000000, processorArchitecture=msil

ERROR SUMMARY
Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
* Error occurred during store lookup, component store may have been corrupted. Following failure messages were detected:
    + Application is not installed.
* Error occurred during uninstall of the application. Following failure messages were detected:
    + Application is not installed.
* Exception occurred during uninstall of application XXXXX.Client.application, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0000000000000000, processorArchitecture=msil. Following failure messages were detected:
    + Shortcut removal could not be completed. Publisher or product value is not valid. 

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
* [4/17/2012 10:52:36 AM] : Looking up information from component store.
* [4/17/2012 10:52:36 AM] : Uninstall of application XXXXX.Client.application, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0000000000000000, processorArchitecture=msil did not succeed.

ERROR DETAILS
Following errors were detected during this operation.
* [4/17/2012 10:52:36 AM] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentException (SubscriptionState)
    - Application is not installed.
    - Source: System.Deployment
    - Stack trace:
        at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.CheckInstalled(SubscriptionState subState)
        at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.CheckInstalledAndShellVisible(SubscriptionState subState)
        at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentServiceCom.MaintainSubscriptionInternal(String textualSubId)
* [4/17/2012 10:52:36 AM] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentException (SubscriptionState)
    - Application is not installed.
    - Source: System.Deployment
    - Stack trace:
        at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.CheckInstalled(SubscriptionState subState)
        at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.UninstallSubscription(SubscriptionState subState)
        at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentServiceCom.MaintainSubscriptionInternal(String textualSubId)
* [4/17/2012 10:52:36 AM] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentException (Subscription)
    - Shortcut removal could not be completed. Publisher or product value is not valid. 
    - Source: System.Deployment
    - Stack trace:
        at System.Deployment.Application.ShellExposure.RemoveSubscriptionShellExposure(SubscriptionState subState)
        at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentServiceCom.MaintainSubscriptionInternal(String textualSubId)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
No transaction information is available.
```

I've tried a number of approaches and nothing seems to work

1. reading the uninstallstring from registry and launch a process.
2. created a vbsript and add it as a custom action. (objShell.Run "rundll32.exe dfshim.dll,ShArpMaintain XXXXX.Client.application, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0000000000000000, processorArchitecture=msil")
3. created a cmd/bat file (that contains rundll32.exe dfshim.dll,ShArpMaintain XXXXX.Client.application, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0000000000000000, processorArchitecture=msil) and launch it while uninstalling.

All the three approaches throws the same error. But when i run them separately all seem to work. I been trying this for over 2 days pulling all my hair out.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm facing the same issue (every approach works from the command line or running my scripts directly, nothing works when including in an installer).